# Main function not called Qt Creator

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

In Qt Creator I have a `main.cpp` file that of course contains the `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and in my `MainWindow.h` file it has code to set up a window, which is functional ( I did not post the code as it is not relevant ). The problem arises when since I am trying to use the msvc compiler (which I have successfully set up), Because when I use the MinGW compiler it runs correctly and sets up the window. However in my `main.cpp` file ->

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

#include "Engine/Window/MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argc);

    std::cout << "Starting application" << std::endl;

    MainWindow w;
    w.execute();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I run the application I don't see `"Starting Application"` I just see `"Press <return> to close the window"` Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I would also like to note that I just used Qt's "auto detect" functionality to find these compilers.

Also my `.pro` file

```
QT += core
QT -= gui widgets

CONFIG += c++14
CONFIG += windeployqt

TARGET = BaneEngine_
CONFIG += console
CONFIG += app_bundle

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/ExtLibs/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/ExtLibs/include
LIBS += -L$$PWD/ExtLibs/libs
LIBS += -lSDL2main -lSDL2test -lSDL2 -lglew32 -lOpenGL32

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    Engine/Window/MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    Engine/Window/MainWindow.h
```

Comment: What is `w.execute()`? Why do you use `QCoreApplication` instead of `QApplication`?

Comment: To see console output in a windows application add CONFIG+=console to your .pro file. Maybe the mingw build does this automatically.

Comment: w.execute() is a function that opens an sdl window. And I will add my .pro file to the queston

Comment: I have the same essential problem in Qt for Android.  Everything worked in Qt 5.2 through 5.5, but it fails in 5.7.  Note that in Qt for iOS, multiple times over Apple changes have forced the main function signature to be modified.  Perhaps there are other such discrepancies that are causing these cross platform / cross compiler issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>

#include "Engine/Window/MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argc);

    std::cout << "Starting application" << std::endl;

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This did not solve the problem, and I would like to note it works if I use the MinGW compiler.